# Phalcon: how to customize scaffold to generate a divs instead of a table?

Tags: phalcon, scaffold

I'm using the scaffold generator of phalcon 
it generates table, below is an example of the generated code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">
            <label for="id_media">Id Of Media</label>
        </td>
        <td align="left">
            {{ text_field("id_media", "type" : "numeric") }}
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    ...
</table>
```

My question is how to customize the generating process to have a form, with divs instead of a table.

Comment: Phalcon scaffolding tool is just a simple helper. You should modify generated code manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's possible by modifying the following, depending on your need

- Modify the views' files in phalcon-tools/templates/scaffold/no-forms/views
- Modify the scaffold.php in /phalcon-tools/scripts/Phalcon/Builder/Scaffold.php

Regards